# Is it good to add symlinks of all 3rd party apps in /usr/bin?

Tags: unix, path, symlink

I install all 3rd party apps in "/opt" which I need to install manually i.e without any package manager.

So to use all those manually installed apps from TERMINAL I need to add them in PATH variable.

But I find that PATH variable should not be longer otherwise it can make system slower, very negligible but it will. So I added symlinks of the executables in a path which is already added in PATH variable like "/usr/bin".

My question is I didn't find any side effects of this technique, it's working well.
But I want to know if there will be any problem later by doing this. As far I know "/usr/bin", "/bin", "/sbin" this folders are managed by package managers. So will it make any problem to package managers by adding symlinks like this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming. It would be a better fit for http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

That would only confuse package managers if the packages might use those same pathnames.  There are a few drawbacks to the symlink approach:

- you have to maintain the links (and remember to remove broken links if you remove the packages which they correspond to).
- occasionally you will encounter a package which is run via a shell script that checks to see where it is run from (such as the symbolic link in `/usr/bin`) and then assumes that all of its other parts are available on the same path (again `/usr/bin`).  If that extends into sibling directories such as `/usr/lib`, it can be tedious to manage the links.

One way to deal with the links would be to make a meta-package of your own which installs the packages and adds your own post-install/uninstall rules to maintain the links.

Comment: Then you are basically asking to make .deb files of all those apps because its ubuntu. But I didn't understand why package mangers will confuse. If I install mongoDB and add a symlink as /usr/bin/mongo then why any other app will create same symlink. Other app will create symlink of its own name. Then why package manager will confuse?? Other 2 reasons are true though. @Thomas-Dickey

Comment: If the package manager *knows* that a given pathname belongs to more than one package, it generally refuses to install one without removing the other.  The likely cause for conflict would be if you replace a file with one of your symbolic links.